# Keep the values in order of appearance in a multimap

Tags: c++

I have a string that looks like this:

```
let main = 
    let value = 8+2
```

I need to scan it to get this:

```
Type: keyword
Value: "let"

Type: name
Value: "main"

Type: symbol
Value: "="

Type: keyword
Value: "let"

Type: name
Value: "value"

Type: symbol
Value: "="

Type: number
Value: 8

Type: symbol
Value: "+"

Type: number
Value: 2
```

I used a multimap to do it, I'm not going to post the code, because it's too long, but basically it checks every word, and inserts them in my multimap.
It works, all the words are in the multimap, but it doesn't appear in order:

```
Type: keyword
Value: "let"

Type: keyword
Value: "let"

Type: name
Value: "main"

Type: name
Value: "value"

Type: number
Value: 8

Type: number
Value: 2

Type: symbol
Value: "="

Type: symbol
Value: "="

Type: symbol
Value: "+"
```

I have tried with other types of sentences, and other types of Type, but the problem is always the same:
Items appear to be arranged in their order, but not necessarily where they should appear.
I don't know if that's very clear.

Would you help me find a solution :) ?

PS: Sorry for the length of the message, but I prefer to be clear in my explanations and examples.

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) : *"Multimap is an associative container that contains a sorted list of key-value pairs"*. The elements are sorted by key, regardless of the order of insertion. If you want to preserve order, use a sequential container.

Comment: This isn't c++ code, BASIC or something else I dunno.

Comment: Presumably you could use std::map<Key, std::list<Value>>. Then you can control the ordering of the Values in the list.

Comment: >François Andrieux: What sequential container do you recommend?
In C++ with the basic headers, there is only String, Array, Vector, Deque and List.
None of them can keep two values, like a dictionary if I am not mistaken.
>TheDude: I haven't posted any c++ code in my post, there is no BASIC either, it's F# that I try to parse thanks to C++.
>john: I had already thought about it, only, it doesn't fit with the rest of the program (and it has to...), thank you anyway!

Comment: @JCN All of those can contain whatever you want (with a few restrictions), including multiple values. You could make a `std::vector` of a `struct` that has all the elements you need, or even of `std::tuple`. For example, `std::vector<std::tuple<int, std::string>>`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a good idea, I'll apply it immediately.

Comment: I would suggest using `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, value_t>>` where `value_t` is the type of the data you want to store. `std::vector` preserves the order in which elements are added. If you are unsure about your `value_t`, have a look at `std::variant`.